# How to invoke a parameter to a void class?

Tags: java, itext, text-extraction

I am dealing with the text extraction from pdf. To this end I wrote my own text extraction 
strategy. I have one dynamic class and within this class i invoke text extraction strategy.
However, when i introduce some parameters to my dynamic class i cannot use them within strategy class. To be clear i am adding my code template below.

My question is briefly, is it possible to invoke parameter unq showing up in "get_intro" class, from  renderText? Or other way around, can a variable or parameter created inside the "renderText" class be invoked in the "get_intro"?

```
public class trial {

public trial(){}

    public  Boolean get_intro(String pdf, String unq){

    try { ....

            for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
            out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, j, semTextExtractionStrategy));
            }
...} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

semTextExtractionStrategy part:

```
public class SemTextExtractionStrategy implements TextExtractionStrategy {
    @Override
public void beginTextBlock() {
}

@Override
public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {                       

    text = renderInfo.getText();...}

    @Override
public void endTextBlock() {
}

@Override
public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
}

@Override
public String getResultantText() {
    //return text;
    return main;
}
}
```

Comment: Well, one option is to just add a variable for unq in the trial class? You could store this data so it can be accessed by the SemTextExtractionStrategy class, but without the full details of all classes involved, it's hard to really say.

Answer (score 0):

One could consider the following problematic solution:

```
public abstract class DefaultTextExtractionStrategy<D>
       implements TextExtractionStrategy {
    protected D documentInfo;

    public final void setDocumentInfo(D documentInfo) {
        this.documentInfo = documentInfo;
    }

public class SemTextExtractionStrategy extends DefaultTextExtractionStrategy<SemDoc> {
    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock() {
        documentInfo ...
    }

public class SemDoc {
    public String unq:
}
```

And in get_intro:

```
       SemDoc semDoc = new SemDoc();
       semDoc.unq = unq;
       semTextExtractionStrategy.setDocumentInfo(semDoc);
       out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, j, semTextExtractionStrategy));
```

The problem is that you want to pass some context class on calling the entry function (like ActionEvent or such). But by its name a strategy class probably is a stateless singleton. In the above solution you would need to instantiate from a `Class<TextExctractionStrategy>, Class<D>` a new strategy instance. Or like in the MouseAdapter class pass the same event class parameter to every method.

This smells of "over-designing" or a skewed pattern application.

As we are on the brink of Java 8 lambdas, you might even consider a "backport" of a design with lambdas.

But for the moment I would go with adding a generic `D textExtractionContext` to every called function, if the API is not for an external library.

Comment: Thank you @Joop Eggen for your answer. But as a not so experienced java user I am a bit confused with instantiating a new strategy class. when i added the first part of your solution everything went well. However, adding TextExtractionStrategy<SemDoc> part introduced an error as "Interface may not extend a non-interface type". And method does not override any superclass method. Indeed I do not know how to create SemDoc part?

Comment: You would need to make some specific doument info bearing class and make TextExtractionStrategy as either an abstract base class (extends) or extend from a parametrised DefaultTextExctractionStrategy implementing the TextExtractionStrategy. I correct the answer.

Comment: As i see documentInfo under DefaultTextExtractionStrategy is not populated automatically. When i debug it, it looks null under SemTextExtractionStrategy. How can i populate documentInfo with unq variable from "get_intro". Or am i understanding totally wrong? @Joop Eggen